# Why we need an egg cell donor and a surrogate mother in an organism cloning process?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, cloning

Could a whole set of artificial organism-cloning process only be operated on the  somatic nuclear donor ,which means for example ,can we extract the somatic nuclear from animal "A" and put it into the egg cell plasma also from animal "A"  then implant it into the animal"A"'s uterus to clone "A" ?

Answer (score 5):

> Could a whole set of artificial organism-cloning process only be
>   operated on a somatic nuclear donor?

No, this would not be possible. Single-cell reprogramming would enable you to *reset* the potency status of that cell up, yielding an embryonic stem cell (ESC). However, ESC do not have the ability to generate extra-embryonic structures (e.g. placenta), which are known to be required for providing oxygen and nutrients to the embryo, [amongst other relevant functions](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8935436).

*Theoretically*, it could be possible to replicate the embryological environment, and I think this is the second part of your statement. Nevertheless, in practice this is not possible... the amount of signals and parameters that one would need to control simultaneously is far too extensive.

I don't quite see the point of having an enucleated egg and performing somatic cell transfer, when you're not really interested in implantation *in utero*. Somatic cell reprogramming would be sufficient (see [iPSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_pluripotent_stem_cell))

Comment: thanks ! Now I gain some new knowledge now , but there is a little bit misunderstood , what I mean is that ,for example ,if we get a somatic cell from animal "A" , can we just transfer that cell to animal A's uterus to clone animal"A",instead of finding another surrogate mother or egg cell donor?

Comment: @Snake From your comment and your newly edited question I see what you mean. You are wondering whether it is possible to clone an animal by using its own somatic cells AND eggs.

I do not have extensive experience with transgenic production, but I have a hypothesis on why the same female is not used as a donor and for implantation: oocyte extraction is an invasive method that may be destructive (i.e. the donor female dies). Therefore, it is not possible to use the same female and a foster mother is required.

Answer (score 0):

the trick is ovum come with a whole package of signal pathways built in before fertilization that you need to trigger implantation and embryonic development. In theory you could engineer these (search artificial ovum)  but it is drastically easier and less expensive to just use existing ovum organisms produce for essentially free.

could you use ovum and somatic components from the same organism that is the surrogate mother, sure, but there is not much reason to do so. You still need a donor egg and surrogate mother they just all happen to be the same individual.